# How to bind a combobox to the cells in a grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress 10.2.8 for WinForms. I'm trying to show a `ComboxBoxEditRepositoryItem` in the cell when user make clicks combo box item inside the cell.

I defined a Product class to make the binding for my `DataSource` in the grid like this:

```cs
private class Product
{
    public String Product { get; set;}

    public String Testing { get; set; }

    public string AutoTesting{ get; set; }

    public string Limit { get; set; }           
 }
```

All is fine with the grid. I mean, it visualize all my data. But when I try to put data in the `ComboxBoxEditRepositoryItem` associated with the `ColumnEdit`, nothings happens. Something like this :

```cs
repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add("Hello");
repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add("world");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repositoryItemComboBox` is quite unfortunate control, since it doesn't use DataSource property.

I would suggest you fill items after binding your data to the gridview:

```
repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.AddRange(productsData.Select(p => p.Product).ToArray();
```